# How to send XML data as a parameter in PHP using SoapClient

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to implement a web service.
It works perfectly when I use SoapUI and send raw XML request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://ws.wsdomain.com">
       <soap:Header/>
       <soap:Body>
          <web:mainFunction>
             <login>
                <loginData>
                   <name>Freak</name>
                   <password>qwerty</password>
                </loginData>
             </login>
             <xmlData>
             <![CDATA[
             <data>
              <id>123456</id>
              <value>69</value>
             </data>
            ]]>
           </xmlData>
          </web:mainFunction>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

But if I try to use PHP SoapClient it simply won't work.

```
<?php

class loginData {var $name = 'Freak'; var $password = 'qwerty';}
class login {var $loginData;} 
class login_input {var $login;}

$loginData = new loginData;
$login = new login;
$login->loginData = $loginData;

$login_input = new ins;
$login_input->login = $login;        

$xml = '<data>
         <id>123456</id>
         <value>69</value>
        </data>';

class xmlData {var $xmlData;}
$xmlData = new xmlData;
$xmlData->xmlData = $xml;   
class xml_input {var $xmlData;}
$xml_input = new xml_input;
$xml_input->xmlData = $xmlData;  

$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://test.ws.wsdomain.com/files/services/structure?wsdl", array('trace' => 1,'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE)); 
$ws_result = $soapClient->mainFunction($login_input,$xml_input,true);
```

It throws:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'xmlData' property

The first parameter (login) works fine. But the second with the XML data is a total pain in the a..

I tried almost everything (instead of simple XML string in a $xml variable I also tried to put it into a simplexml object using simplexml_load_string function) but nothing seems to work.

Comment: The manual to the ws says that chunked transfer encoding should be disabled. I don't think this might be the problem in this case however I would like to make sure this is disabled but I dont know how..